# Motorola MC75A RFID cannot find rfidapi32.dll

Tags: rfid, windows-mobile-6.5, motorola, motorola-emdk

I am trying to run one of the SDK RFID samples on a Motorola MC75A (windows), but I am getting the following error - can anyone help? thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the MC75A does not have UHF RFID, but only HF RFID which does not work with the samples and .dll provided with the EMDK.
I have worked on the MC75A a year ago and you had to download a different package for that.
Please let me know if this is not the case with your device.
You might solve this problem in two ways:

- Downloading what Motorola calls: "HF RFID API and Samples v81.01.00 for MC75A"
- If that does not work maybe you have a corrupted OS in which case you might need to reinstall it (I don't think this is the case).

Good luck!

Comment: I downloaded the .net 2008 sdk samples but when I run the program it the rfid is not active?

Comment: What do you mean not active? From what I remember the sample should have sufficient methods for connecting to the RFID Reader, running inventory and other usual operations. You need to remember that HF RFID does not have the same range and performance as UHF RFID, so reading distance will only be a few centimeters. I haven't used the C sample myself but I used the code to guide me in a C# application with all the basic functions marshaled into .NET. It works pretty good and the marshaling is not very difficult from what I can remember.